# Is it possible to sort Cofoundry custom entities by fields in the data model?

Tags: cofoundry

Assume a custom entity booking like this:

```
public class BookingDataModel : ICustomEntityDataModel
{
  public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to query the database for custom entities of type Booking and order the result by ArrivalData (besides loading all bookings into to memory and then sort them using C#)? Or is this asking too much of the custom entity framework?

I am aware that the data model is serialized as JSON and as such not readily sortable in SQL (although newer SQL server versions can do it) - but perhaps the Cofoundry framework has some tricks up it's sleeves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of v0.9 sorting/filtering on custom entity model data is not directly supported. [Issue 318](https://github.com/cofoundry-cms/cofoundry/issues/318#issuecomment-493585288) discusses workaround with building a search index, and there are open issues for implementing similar features.

Comment: Added a feature request for JSON sorting: https://github.com/cofoundry-cms/cofoundry/issues/410. The same idea can of course be applied for WHERE filters.